# Query AD group members in C++ / MFC application / ADsOpenObject

Tags: c++, active-directory, mfc

I'm trying to include a query of AD group members to an (ancient) C++ MFC application, and the only way I've figured out it could be done is using `ADsOpenObject`, which requires me to do `#include <iads.h>`, and that doesn't work well at all:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE\afxv_w32.h
> (16): fatal error C1189: #error:  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>

Am I just missing a `#define` that I need to add or is something else in the app causing this to go terribly wrong?

Or am I even trying to do this using totally wrong libraries?

Comment: Maybe try moving the `#include <iads>` line to *after* all the MFC-related includes?

Comment: Ah, of course. Why didn't I think anything that simple :) Just thought in my head that this must be a fundamental problem...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just as simple as described in the comments -- changing inclusion order fixed the problem.